# Batch process to move file having Date in YYYYMMDD format from one folder to another folder

Tags: batch-file

I am able to move the files without taking date into consideration with the command: `MOVE` through Batch process.

```
move C:\DESTINATION\FILE.txt C:\DESTINATION\
```

But as my file contains date format and I need to move the files based on current date.

Comment: you want to read the file first and then move to the according folder?

Comment: It's still interesting how many people use folders in the root directory instead of their home, despite this being painful since Vista.

Comment: @Joey: I'm not sure what you mean. A root folder, even the system drive root folder, isn't a system folder. An admin can create a sub-folder in `C:\ ` without any request for elevated rights. Not sure about *users*, but I presume that most people (home users at least) run their systems under the default accounts, which are admin accounts.

Answer (score 1):

You can get the current date with `wmic`:

```
for /f "skip=1" %%x in ('wmic os get localdatetime') do if not defined MyDate set MyDate %x
set MyDate=%MyDate:~0,8%
```

and then just move them:

```
move %MyDate%.txt destination
```

Comment: @ECHO OFF cd C:\SOURCE set ttrn=none for /F "tokens=2-4 delims=/ " %%i in ('date /t') do set ttrn=%%k%%i%%j mput SAM*.txt move *%ttrn%*..txt C:\DESTINATION\

Answer (score 0):

move "Filename%date:~10,4%%date:~4,2%%date:~7,2%.txt" "C:\Destination\Folder\"

EDIT: This format works with the English (United States) date format. It's quick and gritty =D

Comment: This is locale-sensitive, though and thus needs to be adapted depending on the user's locale setting.